# Geometry Generator - make line to polygon perimiter

Tags: qgis, labeling, geometry-generator

I would like to improve the way arrows point to polygons when moving labels. I have some fields with unique numbers associated with each one. When the centroid of a polygon is outside the physical feature, the arrow will be misguiding. How can I improve my expression for the arrow to point to the perimiter of the polygons as illustrated with the blue circles?

[image]

```
CASE 
WHEN 
("auxiliary_storage_labeling_positionx" IS NOT NULL AND "auxiliary_storage_labeling_positiony" IS NOT NULL) THEN make_line(centroid($geometry),make_point("auxiliary_storage_labeling_positionx","auxiliary_storage_labeling_positiony"))
ELSE
NULL
END
```

EDIT:

Can anything be done to prevent the arrow appearing a second time if the centroid does not sit on the surface of the polygon as shown below?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **difference** to cut the arrow by the polygon (`$geometry`).

In your case, change

```
make_line(centroid($geometry),
          make_point("auxiliary_storage_labeling_positionx", 
                     "auxiliary_storage_labeling_positiony"))
```

to

```
difference(make_line(centroid($geometry),
           make_point("auxiliary_storage_labeling_positionx", 
                      "auxiliary_storage_labeling_positiony")), $geometry)
```

---

**[EDIT]**

If the centroid is not within the body of polygon, `point_on_surface` might be more appropriate.

Please try:

```
difference(make_line(point_on_surface($geometry),
           make_point("auxiliary_storage_labeling_positionx", 
                      "auxiliary_storage_labeling_positiony")), $geometry)
```

Comment: thanks for answering the above it's made life a lot easier. I've made a slight amendment to the question. Would you spare a minute to see if it is possible? Many thanks

Comment: Hi @JamesB Could you try a modified expression in the edited section?